# Can I add new shared directories to Docker from the command line?

Tags: configuration, command-line-interface, docker

This is apparently only available from a preference panel or window, and I only have ssh access. Trying to run what I think should have been made available gives me "The path is not shared and is not known to Docker" error message.

Nothing in the help message indicates it can do this, I can't find anything in the documentation, and strangely SO sites don't seem to have a question about this.

At this point I'd settle for a command that even listed which directories were allowed so I could see if I'm mistyping this somehow. Is this a gui-only feature?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/

Comment: @EEAA That mostly talks about how to mount/access volumes for a specific container. From the link "your Docker Engine daemon has only limited access to your macOS or Windows filesystem. " But no command on that page that I can tell let's you expand that access. Or list the access. Or maybe I'm just not understanding the terminology.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? It seems as if you may be trying to use Docker in a way it's not intended to be used. Please edit your question and give details on your use case, what you've tried, etc. Your container should be started with access to all of the resources it needs (via CLI commands), and if those needs change at some point, the container should be re-launched.

Comment: I'm supposed to make a volume with this particular container via -v. The place I need this volume to mount to barfs... either I never configured docker to have access to that directory, or I'm misspelling it and cannot tell how. If I could list the directories docker allows for this purpose, or if I could even add one, that'd be great. I'm just running a web app... something docker is supposed to be able to do. That's why someone created this image.  http://www.space-rocket.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/docker-file-sharing-preferences.png

Comment: Note that the screenshot you provided is coming from Docker for Mac and the [feature](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/)  this relates to is only available on macOS, where it is meant primarily for development purposes (just as the whole product on that platform is meant for dev use only, not for production use) and is really only necessary due to the fact that there is no native Linux OS available and the whole shebang has to run in a specialized Linux VM.